# "Invalid Page" for Visualforce Page on Community Builder

Tags: community, community-builder

I've a lightning component which loads a visualforce page to load a video like below:

```
<iframe src="{! v.urlPrefix + '/video?Id=' + v.videoId }"/>
```

I get the urlPrefix from the component controller like below:

```
String communityId = Network.getNetworkId();
if (communityId != null) {
    if(ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(communityId) != null && ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(communityId).urlPathPrefix != null) {
        return '/' + ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(communityId).urlPathPrefix;
    }
}

return '/apex';
```

This works fine in Community & Out-side community but the same gives "Invalid Page" in Community Builder while building/editing the page.

Any suggestions.